# Removing Duplicates From Foreach Php

Tags: php

This is my goal trying to remove duplicates and also keep matched from the exploded value and the $classQuery statement selected

[image]

```
$examQuery = $examClass->get_examByID($id);

$examRow = $examQuery->fetch_assoc();

$classes = explode(',', $examRow['class_id']);

$classQuery2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE `school_id` = '{$examRow['school_id']}' ");
if ($classQuery2->num_rows < 1):
    $output .= '';
else:

    while ($class_rows = $classQuery2->fetch_assoc()):
        foreach ($classes as $class):
            if ($class_rows['class_id'] === $class):
                $output .= '<option selected value="' . $class_rows['class_id'] . '">' . $class_rows['class_title'] . '</option>';
            else:
                $output .= '<option value="' . $class_rows['class_id'] . '">' . $class_rows['class_title'] . '</option>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Are you comparing the **`class_id`** (I suppose that It's integer Type) with **`$class`** which type is Object ?? 
In line 14: `if ($class_rows['class_id'] === $class):`

Comment: `$classes` is an array of IDs and consequently `$class` is an id. So that part should be OK ...

Comment: but am getting duplicates which i don't want

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to resolve this simply by putting a GROUP BY on your query;

`$classQuery2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM`class`WHERE`school_id`= '{$examRow['school_id']}' GROUP BY class_id");`

Otherwise, I'd probably keep an array of ones already used and check if the key is in that before echoing;

For example;

```
// the array of items to loop over (which has a duplicate in it)
$myArray = ['english', 'maths', 'science', 'geography', 'english'];

// an array to place the item name when it's been used once
$alreadyUsed = [];

foreach($myArray as $item) {
    // if the item doesn't already exist in $alreadyUsed then 
    // echo it out and add it to the array.
    if (! in_array($item, $alreadyUsed)) {
        echo $item . "<br>";
        $alreadyUsed[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please am not getting it

Comment: What are you not getting? Does that not work or do you not understand my answer?

Comment: Change your query to this: $classQuery2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROMclassWHEREschool_id= '{$examRow['school_id']}' GROUP BY class_id");

Comment: Then refresh in your browser

Comment: i have done as instructed but i think my problem is coming from the while loop and foreach loop ... please i beg u help me analyze my code u get my problem

Comment: You need to die(var_dump($classQuery2->fetch_assoc()); just after the else and return the response here. Will need to see what is being returned

Comment: the returned value from the database is like this (1,2,4)

Answer (score 0):

### You are comparing different Types!

If you want a good comparasion, you'll need to compare the values with the same type 
e.g **`Integer === Integer`** || **`String === String`** || **`Object === Object`**

---

In your case, you have to compare the $class_rows['class_id'] with your class **ID**, 
Something like that:

```
if ($class_rows['class_id'] === $class.id):
            # Successful Condition
else:
            # Unsuccesful Condition
endif;
```

Comment: You haven't closed the if with endif;

Comment: Also what is $class.id? $class is an integer (well far more likely a string which just looks like a number). Since databases very often return a number as a string this OP's type comparison should have no issues.

Comment: Thanks R.Garcia the major problem is to remove the duplicates